# Installing Primer3

Tags: windows, command-line, makefile, mingw32, primer3

I need to install Primer3 for my research in Windows, and I really have no idea of how to go about it. I was following the instructions mentioned [here](http://primer3.sourceforge.net/primer3_manual.htm#installWindows).

I'm getting to the part where I need to run

```
    mingw32-make TESTOPTS=--windows
```

and I keep getting an error saying:

```
    'mingw32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Just for reference, I went into the minGW Installation manager and got the ming32-make packages, including the bin, doc, lang, and lic ones, because I really had no idea which one was the correct one.
If someone could help me, I would be very grateful! Installing these niche programs without an installation wizard is a challenge!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install `mingw32-make`. This is a
Windows of port of [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/),
a software-build tool that is supported on all operating systems,
indeed the daddy of such tools.

But `make` alone will not suffice. To build `primer3` you will
need a Windows port of the whole GNU toolchain for building software
from source code. Without that, running `make` by itself will
just expose the absence of the [GCC compiler and linker](https://gcc.gnu.org/) that it
expects to do its bidding.

This is quite a lot of software, but it is easy and quick to install and there
are several open-source offerings. I suggest you go to [TDM GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/)
and download the **TDM64 bundle**. This will give you an executable installer.
Just run it and you will end up with the complete GNU toolchain, including,
`mingw32-make`, in your chosen installation directory.

It will also install in your Windows launch menu the **MinGW command prompt**.
Launch this and you will be presented with a Windows commandline console
with its environment set up to find and run any of the GNU tools.

In this console change directory to your primer3-X.Y.Z/test directory
and then run `mingw32-make TESTOPTS=--windows` as per documentation.

Be forwarned that the self-tests of primer3 that are executed to
verify the build may take 1/2 hr. to 1 hr. to run, depending on your
hardware, but they will finish successfully with the steps I've
described, barring problems specific to your machine. It is a foolproof-simple build.
All the built executables are deposited in the `primer3-X.Y.Z/src`
directory. You may want to move them somewhere more convenient
in in your `PATH`.

It does seem oddly amateurish that the documentation simply
directs you to *run mingw32-make* with no preliminary account of
what that is or how to install it, while on the other hand it
advises that you must install `perl` and strongly recommends a
specific `perl` distribution; but evidently primer3 is open-source
scientfic software and its documentation is not bad by the standard
of that genre.

Comment: almost 3 years later I have found this to be very useful! Thanks.